# Can you get back the message that was set during PXProcessing<>.SetError()?

Tags: acumatica

When calling an action in a processing form that performs a `SetError()` for one of the records, is there a way to get to that error message?

In this case, I'm wanting to call an action of a 3rd party add-on's processing form that performs a series of validations against an SOShipment, and if that add-on detects a problem it flags the record as such:

`PXProcessing<PX.Objects.SO.SOShipment>.SetError(index, string.Format("Some Error"));`

When the call to that action returns, I'm not seeing where I can get to those messages.

Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried it myself but it seems that you might be able to get the messages by calling

```
PXProcessing<YourDAC>.GetItemMessage()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've tried that.  I just get a null

Comment: Could you perhaps share more of your code please if possible?